# Add folder name to fgrep result

Tags: bash, perl, command-line

I'm analysing some log files and I'm trying to prepare data with bash. My folder structure looks like this:

```
<main_folder>
    <folder_1>
        <subfolder_1>
            <log_1>
            <log_2>
        <subfolder_2>
            <log_1>
    <folder_2>
        <subfolder1>
            <log_1>
```

I would like to go through every `<folder_n>`and use fgrep to get some lines. I would like to add `<folder_n>` and `<subfolder_n>` names (without full path) to the beginning of every line, separated with blank space lines.

So the result would look something like this:

```
folder_1 subfolder_1 text_1 text_2 text_3
folder_1 subfolder_2 text_1 text_2 text_3
folder_1 subfolder_2 text_1 text_2 text_3
folder_2 subfolder_1 text_1 text_2 text_3
```

I have a command that takes the text lines that I need adds *some* text to the beginning of the result, but I don't know how to add folder names to result lines.

```
fgrep "Print ended" *.txt -a | awk '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $4}' | perl -ne 'print " TEST $_"'
```

My question is: If I am located in `~/main_folder`, how to edit the command

```
fgrep "Print ended" *.txt -a | awk '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $4}'`
```

so that it adds `<folder_n>` and `<subfolder_n>` to fgrep result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grepping all the files from the root folder will naturally produce the full path name in front of each match.

```
cd ../..
grep -Fa "Print ended" */*/*.txt | ...
```

If the wildcard is too broad, the trivial fix is to tighten it.  Your example would match `folder_[12]/subfolder_[12]/*.txt` but I guess in reality your paths are possibly a bit more complex than that.  Bash allows for brace expansion like `{this,other}/{one,two}/*.txt` which expands to `this/one/*.txt`, `other/one/*.txt`, `this/two/*.txt`, `other/two/*.txt`.

It's not clear what exactly your `grep | awk | cut | perl` pipeline does but I guess it will need some adjustment.  Generally, anything that looks like `grep | awk` probably should be reimplemented in Awk or Perl altogether.

```
perl -lnae 'print(join(" ", "TEST", split("/", $ARGV), $F[0], $F[2]))
     if /Print ended/' */*/*.txt
```

Splitting the relative file name in `$ARGV` on slashes and joining with spaces seems counter to reason, but produces the result you are asking about.

Comment: `grep -F` is the modern equivalent to `fgrep` but both should work.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
Could you show me how to edit the command `fgrep "Print ended" *.txt -a` to include described folder names? And from what location should I execute the command?

Comment: That's literally the very first sentence of this answer and the example which follows.  When you run `grep` on multiple files, it prints the matched file's name in front of each match, in exactly the form that you passed it in.  So pass it a bunch of file names with the folder structure and that's what it will print. (Sometimes we add `/dev/null` to force there to be more than one file name; equivalently, `grep -H` forces the file name to be printed.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to do the recursion then you can get the path for each match, e.g.

```
find . -name \*.txt -exec grep "Print ended" {} /dev/null \;
```

Obviously you can pipe the output of this into any further processing you might need to get the results in your required format, but this should be trivial to do.

Comment: result is: "missing argument to `-exec`". I understand that this is seen as trivial to someone who know this, but this does not seem trivial to me.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot the `\;` at the end.